# Restrict user from jumping to any other page on account

Tags: spring-mvc

i am designing a website using spring framework in which i want that when user is not paid i can let him login and he is redirected to account home but he is not able to do anything else(when he tries to do something he is redirected to account home) but i don't want to keep a check on each and every operation individually.I would like it to be handled from one place. Also in the case when user is logged in and his paid membership period ends.

Comment: Use spring security, assign role to user, based on role give excess to url pattern.

Comment: thanks,can you please elaborate a bit more as i am new to spring

Comment: Spring security provide way to give access to url for particular role of user. It will define in spring-security.xml file where you can give url access to particular role. this is sample tag `<intercept-url pattern="/customer/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />`

Comment: I tried implementing this by defining  different roles for paid and unpaid user.But i am facing problem in providing them access when unpaid user upgrades into paid user.

Comment: After upgrade may force user to relogin or auto login it self and set new role to user.